# tkinter freezing despite threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I am currently developing a web scanner that continuously scans for vulnerable URLs.
I wanted a GUI for my program and thus chose to use tkinter.

Currently I am facing a problem where when I call from my main program (the GUI) by pressing a button to the other scripts, the GUI will freeze and will only load up when the program is done scanning with the entire wordlist.

I know of threading and have tried to apply it to my program. But it doesn't seem to be working and I am unsure why.

I've browsed through many stackoverflow pages for hours and implementing them and it still doesn't seem to work out. One example I've tried is [python running task in the background while allowing tkinter to be active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514006/python-running-task-in-the-background-while-allowing-tkinter-to-be-active)

My codes are as follows:

Main GUI

```
from Tkinter import *
from URLFuzzerNonRecursive import nonrecursiveURL
import threading

def thread(value):
   t = threading.Thread(target=nonrecursiveURL(value))
   t.start()
   #t.join()

def main():
   master = Tk()
   master.title("Web Fuzzer")

   master.geometry("700x400")
   urllabel = Label(master, text="Input URL to Fuzz")
   urllabel.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.05)
   urlinput = Entry(master, bd =5)
   urlinput.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.10)
   urlinput.insert(END,"http://")

   nonrecursionURL = Button(master, text="Non-Recursive URL Fuzzer", command=lambda: thread(urlinput.get()),width=20, height=2)
   nonrecursionURL.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.30)

   master.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Python Script called by main GUI:

```
import requests
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def nonrecursiveURL(URLtoTake):
   root = tk.Tk()

   ybar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
   T = tk.Text(root)
   ybar.config(command=T.yview)
   T.config(yscrollcommand=ybar.set)
   T.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)
   ybar.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="ns")
   try:
    with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            website = URLtoTake.strip('\n')+"/" + line
            URL = requests.get(website)
            if URL.status_code == 200:
                foundsites.append(website)
                info_message = "Status code: "+ str(URL.status_code) + " Found :" + website
                T.insert(tk.END,info_message)

            else:
                info_message = "Status code: "+ str(URL.status_code) +" Not Found :" + website
                T.insert(tk.END,info_message)

        for i in foundsites:
            T.insert(tk.END,"\n")
            T.insert(tk.END,"Found : ")
            T.insert(tk.END, i)
   except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
       info_message = "Please enter a valid URL ( inclusive of http:// )"
       tkmb.showinfo("Output", info_message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `thread` function posted in the question is **calling** the `nonrecursiveURL` function directly, before passing it as the thread target.

```py
def thread(value):
   t = threading.Thread(target=nonrecursiveURL(value)) <-- here nonerecursiveURL is being called
```

To call a function in a different thread, the [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) instance requires a function reference, and an optional list of arguments to be passed to that function.

```py
t = threading.Thread(target=nonrecursiveURL, args=(value,))
```

now `nonrecursiveURL` is not called in here, but only passed to the `Thread`, and will be called in a different thread, when `t.start()` is called.

You can confirm this issue, by just calling the `thread` function from Python REPL, leaving Tkinter out of the debugging session.